# Background color is not totally rendered using viewport?

Tags: iphone, html, css

This is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1; user-scalable=1;' />
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        #main
        {
            position:relative;
            background-color:#454a4b;
        }    


        #inside
        {
            width:900px;
            position:relative;
        }    
    </style>

    <div id="main">
        <div id="inside">
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

if I watch it on iPhone, the background color is rendered only on the space viewed when the page load. If I scroll to right, I see that the background is not taken.

Why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: put the `background-color` property into the `body` css block instean of `#main`.

Comment: No, I can't (I have some other body background).